# Accessing a property from a management pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-bom

In our project, we use a dependency-management pom which is imported into another maven project's pom. The dependency management pom has some properties. Is there a way to access the properties from the dependency management pom?

Also, I looked at other options. Having the dependency-management pom as a parent pom, but the maven project's pom already has a parent pom declared so that is not an option.

Using [properties-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html), but I am not sure how to access the property from another pom using this plugin.

Below is the structure am working with.

** dependency-management pom:

```
<project>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <groupId>group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <name>management-pom</name>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <test.version>0.2</test.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group2</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependencies>
     <dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

** pom where dependency-management pom is imported:

```
<project>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>group3</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact3</artifactId>
    <name>war-pom</name>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <properties>
        <!--how to access the dependency-management pom's properties here?-->
        <maven.test.version>${test.version}</maven.test.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group2</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group1</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependencies>
     <dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

The closest question I found was [Access maven property using dependency management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698654/access-maven-property-using-dependency-management) which was asked 4 years ago and it did not have an answer that I was looking for.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use that property which is from the BOM file?

Comment: The property tag in the pom `<maven.test.version>${test.version}</maven.test.version>` is being used in one of the classes for accessing a link populated with the retrieved version. Example: `http://example.com/${maven.test.version}`. For this am currently making use of an existing maven-resources-plugin.

Comment: Why do you need to access a version within a java class?

Comment: for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this plugin https://gitlab.com/josh-cain/dependencyversion-maven-plugin.

This did the job of getting the dependency version from the pom that was getting imported.

So using this plugin, now I am able to directly access the version of the dependency which was getting exported as a property using this plugin.

Used the below snippet in the code.

`${group2:artifact2.jar.version}`