# How to activate a profile if a phase is activated?

Tags: maven

Is there a way to activate a Maven profile only if a project is (or is not) being deployed?

[nexus staging plugin](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins/tree/master/staging/maven-plugin) deploys all modules that are part of a reactor build so I want to skip certain modules (unit tests, benchmarks, etc) if the project is being deployed (to deploying them).

I know I can invoke `mvn -Ddeploy deploy` and activate profiles based on the `deploy` property but I'm hoping there is a way to avoid mentioning `deploy` twice.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot do that.

There is list of possible profile activations (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), stating:

> A profile can be triggered/activated in several ways:
>
> - Explicitly
> - Through Maven settings
> - Based on environment variables
> - OS settings
> - Present or missing files

My guess is that profiles are evaluated *before* the phases/goals are even read by Maven.  I tried to figure it out from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727072/927493, but it does not say it explicitly.

It may help, though, to set `<skip>true</skip>` for the deploy plugin in the respective modules (the property `maven.deploy.skip` could also be used).

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html